# Spring Cloud aggregation , not able to understand how to identify the structure of aggregated message which will be consumed by the sink process

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I want to know how to understand the message structure which will be consumed by the sink method .

```java
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
class UsageCostAggregator {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsageCostProcessorApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    Processor processor;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT)
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler aggregator() {

        AggregatingMessageHandler aggregatingMessageHandler =
                new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(),
                        new SimpleMessageStore(10));

        AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setOutputChannel(processor.output());
        //aggregatorFactoryBean.setDiscardChannel(processor.output());
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendTimeout(1000L);
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setCorrelationStrategy(new ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy("'FOO'"));
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(3)); //ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy("size() == 5")
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(3000L)); //size() ge 2 ? 5000 : -1
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
        logger.info("Releasing messages: " + aggregatingMessageHandler.toString());
        return aggregatingMessageHandler;
    }
}
```

2. I also tried to add below methods  ... but these methods were not used ...

```java
    @org.springframework.integration.annotation.CorrelationStrategy
    public String correlateBy(@Header("kafka_receivedTopic") String id) {
        return id;
    }

    int MessageAggregationSize=5;

    @ReleaseStrategy
    public boolean release(List<Message<String>> messages) {
        if(messages.size() == (MessageAggregationSize != 0 ? MessageAggregationSize : 1)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Aggregator
    public List<UsageDetail> aggregateMessages(List<UsageDetail> messages){
        List<Message<UsageDetail>> aggMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        //aggMessages.addAll(UsageDetail);
        return messages;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is; the default output processor will emit a single message with a `List<IncomingPayload>` as its payload. The annotated methods are not used when you define the aggregator as a `@Bean` like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gary ......  In my case,   1. Source: I am sending object of class "usageDetail"     2. Aggregation: For aggregation, I am using "aggregator()" method shown above.    3. Sink: At sink i am getting list of String ... not list of objects of "usageDetail", which i am sending from sender.   How can i get the list of object in sink ?